# How to make a apk packages manually like other linux distro packages?

Tags: android, apk

Because Android Linux-based and it has its own package format named APK, so it will be possible to create [APK packages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apk_(file_format)) manually from a specification like a specification for `pacman` packages in Arch Linux.

But I can't find a Specification for APK packages as self-explanatory as other distro packages like [`pacman` (Arch) specification](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Creating_packages).

How to make an APK package by packing compiled files and others manually like for Linux distros?

Comment: Hello and welcome to RE.SE! I can't see how this is related to reverse engineering.

Comment: @Smm Welcome to RE.SE. Android can hardly be described as a GNU/Linux distro. Because the GNU part is missing. Sure, you can skip the fact that conventionally Linux distros are defined by kernel+userland and insist on it being purely about the Linux kernel, but even then the relationship to other Linux package formats is distant. APKs are an extension of JARs which themselves are glorified ZIP files. [apktool](https://apktool.org/) can do what you want. That's the only relation I see to reverse engineering (!= RCE). As it stands I have to agree with sudhackar.

Comment: Even Arch uses tooling for package creation (`makepkg(8)`, `pacman(8)`), so I am not sure what it is you want exactly. So you should edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Thanks , for editing kindly mr "0xC0000022L"

Comment: Yes "arch uses tooling for package Creation"  but its enough transparent about how its works for example I know it moves some files into some standard directories and track them  its simple as I can create a package manager like this of Linux but I can't reach transparency like this in apk files and how they operate also how to pack them in most optimized way what community you suggest to move question into it ?

Comment: I think the whole post is a misunderstanding. APK is not a package format like it is used in Linux distros, it is an app package format. Apps are running in a sandbox with a specified API where as Linux packages like  deb, rpm, ... are software packages that are integrated into the Linux installation. Are you sure this is not a confusion with the Alpine Package Keeper (APK) which manages the packages for Alpine Linux systems?

Comment: No , I'm not confused in this way and by apk i don't mean Alpine Package keeper by apk transparency (Linux package managers are transparent for me) is a key I'm looking for it in apk to open doors of creativity and flexibility in development also when I know how this works it will prevent me from security holes @Robert